# Print part of a page javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I have a problem. I'm trying to print out only content which is in a div, basically everything below the buttons (See picture below).
[image: Div content]

But then i try to print, the result looks something like this:
[image: preing preview]

I.e. without any stylesheets.

But the code includes all the css files I currently have.

This is the function I have. I have tried with or without the stylesheets and different ways to reference them. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
function PrintHistory() {
        var printDivCSS5 = new String(
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jqGrid.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/jqgrid-smoothness-ui.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/ui.fancytree.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/site.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/bootstrap.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/Hepper.mms.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/bootstrap-select.css">' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:62533/Content/themes/base/typeahead.css">');

        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
        var prtContent = document.getElementById("historyTabeTarget");
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.write("<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + printDivCSS5 + prtContent.innerHTML + "</body>");
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
        prtContent.innerHTML = oldPage;
    };
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see? The blue background behind the heading and grey background behind the content? If so you probably aren't doing anything wrong as browsers tend to disable background colours and images when printing (to save ink I believe).

Comment: Have you heard about [CSS Print Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it can be achieved by CSS. All you need to do is add the following with the CSS specifications for print in your stylesheet.

```
@media print{
    /* your print css */
}
```

Use `display: none;` for all the elements you do not wish to be printed and override the remaining css accordingly.